# Reusing Laravel forms, hiding and showing inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a form partial that I am using for creating and updating users. If I select an account type from a drop down, I want to be able to hide and show inputs based on what is selected. Is there a way to do this? I was trying to use jquery's on change function, but since there will be multiple forms populating in hidden modals for editing users, I can't really do an ID specific selector and classes don't seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would use Vue components. They are pretty easy and elegant, Laravel ships with Vue included: https://vuejs.org/

Comment: @nXu I didn't quite realize what Vue was, I noticed a sample portion of it in the app.js but ignored it because of my newness to Laravel. Reading over the documentation, this seems like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Warning, old school solution without javascript (two pass form):

1) Use the type select inside a form with GET method and action on the same route

2) in the controller action check for the type variable and pass to the view,

3) in the view show the inputs of the second form based on the type or show the type selection form if type is not set.

The second form has POST method and action to to the final post route.

If you want you can use javascript to autosubmit the first form when user select the user type.